# Scrapy - Limiting middle directories (Python)

Tags: python, regex, web-crawler, scrapy

Is there a way in SgmlLinkExtractor rules to only allow a limited number of directories (say 3) between /static/ and /otherstuff/ ?  So in the below example, EX1 would not be crawled (because there are four directories between /static/ and /otherstuff/), but EX2 would be.

EX1: `http://www.domain.com/static/d1/d2/d3/d4/otherstuff/otherstuff2/bunchacrap`

 EX2: `http:///www.domain.com/static/d1/d2/otherstuff/otherstuff2/bunchacrap`

Assume that /static/ and /otherstuff/ are always on either side of the directories I want.

Thanks a TON for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either use a regex in the `allow` parameter or a test function in the `process_value` parameter. (See the [docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.18/topics/link-extractors.html#sgmllinkextractor).)

Both have their pros and cons, it depends how it looks the links in your page. If you use a regex, you test against the fully qualified url (i.e. http://domain.com/foo/bar). If you use the `process_value` parameter you get the raw value found in the webpage (i.e. /foo/bar or worse, a relative link).

For example, the regex `domain.com/(?:\w+/){1,3}\w+$` matches

```
domain.com/foo/bar
domain.com/foo/bar/foo
domain.com/foo/bar/foo/bar
```

But not

```
domain.com/foo/
domain.com/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo
```

If you go with the `process_value`, a function like this would work

```
def filter_path(value):
    # at least 2, at most 3 /'s
    if 1 < value.count('/') < 4:
        return value
```

The function above assumes your html links have href's values like `/foo`, `/foo/bar/foo`, etc.

In your specific case, the regex would be like `domain.com/static/(?:\w+/){3}otherstuff`, and the `filter_path` function might check for `value.startswith('/static/')` and the suffix.

There is a third option if you are using the `Rule` class in a `CrawlSpider`. The `process_links` parameter allows you to pass a function to process the link list. For example

```
def url_allowed(url):
    # check for the pattern /static/dir/dir/dir/ etc
    return True

def process_links(links):
    return [l for l in links if url_allowed(l.url)]
```

Comment: I can't upvote with my rep, but this is amazing - thanks so much for spelling out the alternatives!  I'm actually using this process to learn by trial, so your alternatives taught me a ton.  I'm especially excited to try out the `process_links` and `url_allowed` parameters!